# Вывод строк @strings

Tags: android, строки

Вопрос:

прописываю это значение:

```
holder.txt_version.setText("version : " + item.getVersion_name());
```

в Приложение отображается прим.

> vesion : 7.2.0

Но, после того как пытаюсь вывести из  @string/

```
holder.txt_version.setText("@string/txt_version" + item.getVersion_name());
```

в Приложение отображается прим.

> "@string/txt_version" : 7.2.0

подскажите, в чем ошибка, если в *string.xml* прописано

```
<string name="txt_version">version :</string>
```

Comment: может потому что в кавычках ("") указывается строка для вывода, а ресурсы берутся так -  tvt_version.setText(R.string.txt_version)

Comment: Возможно чтение [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html?hl=ru) поможет вам самостоятельно решить свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
@string/txt_version таким образом можно задать строку только в xml.
```

Программно задается через R класс

```
textView.setText(R.string.txt_version)
```